# How to Fix NoClassDefFoundError in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to build a small user interface using JavaFX, But I'm getting an error like this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class myApp Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

This is my code:
and im using jdk 12.0.2

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class myApp extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Phonebook mybook = new Phonebook();
    launch(args);


}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Group group = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 600, 300);
    scene.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Phone Book");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

This is the Libraries and jdk I'm using:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7bRu.png)

Comment: Have you a look at the documentation https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse

Comment: this javafx-8.9.1.jar looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: @mipa can u suggest different javafx jars?

Comment: According to your image you are mixing two separate sets of javafx jars. They are also located in different folders. This javafx-8.9.1.jar does not seem to belong to the other set of javafx jars.

Comment: @mipa I removed it, and still doesn't work

Comment: Then I can only refer you to the instructions given by José. Follow them exactly. They work. Probably not related to your problem but what is this creation of the Phonebook doing in the main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JavaFX is not a part of the JDK > 9 any more. (Your version is 12.x.x)

Probably this could help you:
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

*(Assuming you are using Maven)* If this does not help, try to clean and build your Application.
Sometimes Maven does not recognize newly added dependencies.

Comment: I'm trying to run it first using the eclipse.. Should I download and install jdk 9 and try?

Comment: @LaelAvraham yes, download the jar if you are using Ant, or simply add it as dependency if you use Maven. Try to add the JavaFX library to your project. I highly recommend that you use Maven.

Comment: No, if you are using JavaFX 12 you should also use JDK 12 and follow the instructions.

Comment: your link is about running it externally.. I'm trying to run it using eclipse

Comment: I've already posted the link with the documentation to run the project using Eclipse, but here you go again: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse